# Cannot resolve symbol 'UseIdentityColumns'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have .NET Core 3 project with migrations (code-first approach)

When I create migrations I have `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot` file

Migration created successfully, but when I make `dotnet ef database update` I have this error.

```
  ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs(18, 18): [CS1061] 'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseIdentityColumns' and no accessible extension method 'UseIdentityColumns' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: double check that all of the references in the project are using .net core 3, it seems that UseIdentityColumns is not present, I can think 2 errors: 1.- some project is not on core 3.0 or not compatible. 2.- using statement is missing

Comment: @Iria I checked the project and it's a class library and .net core 3.1

Comment: I had this error coming from a wrong nuget package, have you checked those?

Comment: Which one do I need to check? Which package is correct?@Iria

Comment: Check all of the nuget packages, do you know how to do it?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/nuget-faq#:~:text=In%20Visual%20Studio%2C%20use%20the,about%20NuGet%20including%20the%20version. and then go package by package seeing the version and the requirements